# Decision tree software/library for knowledge base

Tags: javascript, decision-tree

I have a knowledge base system, but the users feedback that it is quite hard to search for the information. So I am thinking about the decision tree. If the user can find the info by clicking few options, that will be great.

I saw some websites have this feature. (e.g. I encountered an issue, I choose Windows7 -> login issue -> wrong password, then the system will provide the solution)

I want to implement such system, but unfortunately I didn't find any.

Any smart ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd need to construct the tree (like drawing on paper), then implement the nodes as select boxes perhaps.  Save what the user selected together with the feedback.

Comment: @bdares, yes we can do that. But i want to find any real system, so I can use it right away. I don't have much time to build this system by myself.

Comment: You might want to retag your question with html, javascript, or whatever it is that you hope to find such a library, because this is obviously about the implementation rather than the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive Decision Tree looks like a suitable solution for you

http://code.google.com/p/interactive-decision-tree/